# In asp.net , <asp:BoundField tag is not aligning to left

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

i am using asp:BoundField tag under asp:Gridview tag. In this tag i will be getting my data from sql , all that I am able to get but the problem which i am facing here the text label I am not able to align from left its starting from center

```
   <asp:BoundField DataField = "Foo" HeaderText = "Foo"/>
```

So here I am not able to apply inline styles so how should i do it so that the header text starts from left?

Answer (score 0):

Try the code to apply cssclass and apply style in it

```
<asp:boundfield
        sortexpression="LastName"
        datafield="LastName"
        headertext="LastName">
          <itemstyle CssClass="product">
          </itemstyle>
      </asp:boundfield>
```